# More compact version of "ifelse grepl" loop

Tags: r

I have a data.frame with multiple columns and I would like to add another column, at the end of the df, containing specific strings based on what is present in another column.

for example, I have:

```
df <- data.frame(
  "Therapeutic.Use" = c("Epilepsy", "Cancer", "Angina"),
  "Compound" = c("XXX", "YYY", "KKK"))
```

and I am using the following statement to extract information based on what is present in column "Therapeutic Use".

```
df$Target.Organ <- NA
df$Target.Organ <- ifelse(
  grepl("Epilepsy", df$Therapeutic.Use), "Brain",
    ifelse(grepl("Cancer", df$Therapeutic.Use), "Cancer",
      ifelse(grepl("Angina", df$Therapeutic.Use), "Heart", "Other")))
```

And so on. I have a table with 500 different uses, so it would be easier for me to avoid writing 500 `ifelse` statements. Is this possible?

Thank you in advance for the help :)

Comment: `Target <- data.frame(Therapeutic.Use=c("Epilepsy", "Cancer", "Angina"), Target.Organ=c("Brain", "Cancer", "Heart"));
merge(df, Target, all.x=TRUE, sort=FALSE)` or you can use `recode()` from the package `car`

Comment: Remember, `grep`-related functions are for pattern matching parts of strings with (or without) regex. If you don't need fancy regex patterns, use the `fixed = TRUE` argument to significantly speed things up - this is good when you're looking for an exact substring, like if you were labeling any sentence that contained the word "Angina" with "Heart". But you're not doing that - you're doing exact matching of the entire string, which means you can use `%in%` or `==`, the pattern matching functions aren't necessary at all.

Answer (score 3):

Create a lookup-table to left_join on..
Remember to use `stringsAsFactors = FALSE`, or else you will get factorlevels in stead of character...

```
df <- data.frame("Therapeutic.Use" = c("Epilepsy", "Cancer", "Angina"), 
                 "Compound" = c("XXX", "YYY", "KKK"),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)


library ( dplyr )
#create lookup-table (or read in from a csv/excel)
lookup <- data.frame( Therapeutic.Use = unique( df$Therapeutic.Use ),
                      Target.organ = c("Brain", "Cancer", "Heart" ),
                      stringsAsFactors = FALSE )

df %>% 
  #perform left join
  left_join( lookup ) %>% 
  #replace NA in Target.organ with "Other"
  mutate( Target.organ = ifelse( is.na( Target.organ ), "Other", Target.organ ) )


#   Therapeutic.Use Compound Target.organ
# 1        Epilepsy      XXX        Brain
# 2          Cancer      YYY       Cancer
# 3          Angina      KKK        Heart
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Does your solution imply to have ordered matches between rows in the Therapeutic.Use and those in Target.Organ? If so, it would be a bit more complex than the initial solution, where I was looking for certain specific words in all the rows.

Comment: @Mollan, yes.. if you want to join twe data.frames together, the lookup-table must have every unique value of `Therapeutic.Use` , and the `Target.organ` that belongs to it should be in the same row. Post sample data with wider variety to see if things can be sped up..
Also: make sure to read about the several `dplyr`  join options

Comment: Thank you. With my question I wanted to know whether the entries in the lookup had to be ordered. For example, if I have a row with "Prostate Cancer", I would like to automatically have assigned "Cancer" as the target organ (since it includes Cancer) without specifying the exact row in the lookup. In your example, Cancer is always the 2nd row, independently from what is the entry in the original df while, with a grepl command, the result changes according to the input.

Comment: @Mollan, i see. The lookup-table can be in any order, unrelated to the other data.frame but INSIDE the lookup-table, "Prostate Cancer" hàs to be on the same row as "Cancer" in order for the join to succeed.

Answer (score 0):

Try `case_when`:

```
df%>%
   mutate(Target.Organ=case_when(
     grepl("Epilepsy", Therapeutic.Use)~"Brain",
     grepl("Cancer", Therapeutic.Use)~ "Cancer",
     grepl("Angina", Therapeutic.Use)~ "Heart",
     T~"Other"  
   ))
  Therapeutic.Use Compound Target.Organ
1        Epilepsy      XXX        Brain
2          Cancer      YYY       Cancer
3          Angina      KKK        Heart
```

Comment: valid solution, but still a lot of typing on 500 different cases

Answer (score 0):

Just make a dataframe with the organs and therapeutics, and then make a left_join.

```
# Your dataframe
df <- data.frame("Therapeutic.Use" = c("Epilepsy", "Cancer", "Angina"), "Compound" = c("XXX", "YYY", "KKK"))

# Organ dataframe
df2 <- data.frame(Therapeutic.Use = c("Epilepsy", "Cancer", "Angina"),
                  organ = c("Brain", "Cancer", "Heart"))

# Joining dataframes
library(dplyr)
df_done <- left_join(df, df2)

> df_done
  Therapeutic.Use Compound  organ
1        Epilepsy      XXX  Brain
2          Cancer      YYY Cancer
3          Angina      KKK  Heart
```

Answer (score 0):

On your lookup `data.table()` of key-value pairs, use `data.table::setkey()` followed by `dplyr::mutate()` to add a new column onto `df`:

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(
  "Therapeutic.Use" = c("Epilepsy", "Cancer", "Angina"),
  "Compound" = c("XXX", "YYY", "KKK"),
  stringsAsFactors = F)

hash <- data.table(
  "Therapeutic.Use" = c("Epilepsy", "Cancer", "Angina"),
  "Organ" = c("Brain", "Cancer", "Heart"))
setkey(hash, Therapeutic.Use)

df2 <-  mutate(df, Organ = hash[df$Therapeutic.Use]$Organ)

if(any(is.na(df2$Organ)))
  df2[is.na(df2$Organ), ]$Organ <- "Other"

df2

#   Therapeutic.Use Compound  Organ
# 1        Epilepsy      XXX  Brain
# 2          Cancer      YYY Cancer
# 3          Angina      KKK  Heart
```